# RAM Memory in TCL

Tags: memory, tcl

I have a code that creates a global array and when I unset the array the memory is still busy.

I have tried in Windows with TCL 8.4 and 8.6

```
console show

puts "allocating memory..."

update

for {set i 0} {$i < 10000} {incr i} {
 set a($i) $i
}

after 10000

puts "deallocating memory..."

update

foreach v [array names a] {
 unset a($v)
}

after 10000

exit
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the memory is still busy?" What are you measuring and what is your expectation of that measurement?

Comment: I mean that if you run the code above several times, you reach the maximum RAM memory of the computer and the program stops working. I have a program that works with arrays and is intended to work without stop, but it is not the case...

Comment: Sorry, correction, the code above is a simplification of the program I am using... my program is creating new indeces for the array in every loop I run the code...

Comment: It's (substantially) faster to just do `unset a` than that loop over `array names`; `array names` handles some complex cases that make it quite expensive, and overkill for wiping out an array like that.

Answer (score 2):

In a lot of programs, both written in Tcl and in other languages, past memory usage is a pretty good indicator of future memory usage. Thus, as a general heuristic, Tcl's implementation does not try to return memory to the OS (it can always page it out if it wants; the OS is always in charge). Indeed, each thread actually has its own memory pool (allowing memory handling to be largely lock-free), but this doesn't make much difference here where there's only one main thread (and a few workers behind the scenes that you can normally ignore). Also, the memory pools will tend to overallocate because it is much faster to work that way.

Whatever you are measuring with, if it is with a tool external to Tcl at all, it will not provide particularly good real memory usage tracking because of the way the pooling works. Tcl's internal tools for this (the `memory` command) provide much more accurate information but aren't there by default: they're a compile-time option when building the Tcl library, and are usually switched off because they have a *lot* of overhead. Also, on Windows some of their features only work at all if you build a console application (a consequence of how they're implemented).

Comment: I am using the Windows Task Management Tool to see how much resources the TCL program is consuming.
As I said before, my problem is that you reach the maximum RAM memory of the computer with the code above if you repeat it several times...

Comment: Sorry, correction, the code above is a simplification of the program I am using... my program is creating new indeces for the array in every loop I run the code...

Comment: @DonalFellows - Trying to help, stumbled across you from 18 years ago :D https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/Sy5peo7NRPU (Doubt the thread still applies though...)

Comment: The code _as written and shown to us_ won't run out of memory in the way described; Tcl's pretty aggressive about reusing memory once you've stopped using it.